# What is the default optimization level of cargo build --release?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The `rustc` compiler has [four optimization levels](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#opt-level), [just like GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> opt-level
> This flag controls the optimization level.
>
> 0: no optimization, also turns on cfg(debug_assertions) (the default).
> 1: basic optimizations.
> 2: some optimizations.
> 3: all optimizations.
> s: optimize for binary size.
> z: optimize for binary size, but also turn off loop vectorization.

If I make a build with Cargo and its `--release` option, which optimization level is used?

```
cargo build --release
Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.75s
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to [the cargo manual](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#release), the default level for release builds is `-O3`.

```
# The release profile, used for `cargo build --release` (and the dependencies
# for `cargo test --release`,  including the local library or binary).

[profile.release]
opt-level = 3
debug = false
split-debuginfo = '...'  # Platform-specific.
debug-assertions = false
overflow-checks = false
lto = false
panic = 'unwind'
incremental = false
codegen-units = 16
rpath = false
```